# Writing word count in a text file in bash script

Tags: bash, terminal

I am very new into bashscript, how can I write word count, word size and character size in the text file itself? My current code is:

```
#!bin/bash/

echo "start"

cat file #print file.txt

wc -m file #character count
wc -w file # word count
wc -c file # size

echo "end"
```

I want to append the terminal outputs into my text file. Text file should be like this:

...text
The size of this file: x , word count: x , character count: x. How can I do that?

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: This might help: `m=$(wc -m file | awk '{print $1}'); echo "$m"`

Comment: I'd suggest cutting this down to a single `wc` call, eg, `wc -mwc file`; next step would be to capture this output into variables, eg: `read -r chars words bytes fname < <(wc -mwc file)`; at this point you can print the a message using the variables (`$chars`, `$words`, `$bytes`), appending said output to `file`

Answer (score 0):

You mean append the file's metadata to the same file?

Using GNU `wc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} FILE ..." >&2
    exit 1
fi

for file do
    wc -cwm "$file" |
    awk -v file="$file" \
    '{print "File size: "$3", word count: "$1", character count: "$2 >> file}'
done
```

Also works on Busybox `wc`. You can provide multiple files.

Note that if `wc` is given multiple flags, it always prints the numbers in the same order, regardless of the order the flags are given.

From `man wc` (GNU)

> The options below may be used to select which counts are printed, always in the following order: newline, word, character, byte, maximum line length.

However, POSIX says this:

> By default, the standard output shall contain an entry for each input file of the form:

```
"%d %d %d %s\n", <newlines>, <words>, <bytes>, <file>
```

> If the -m option is specified, the number of characters shall replace the  field in this format.

source: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html

I haven't tested on other platforms, but apparently, a POSIX compliant `wc` would need two separate invocations to get both byte and character count. The reasoning for using one was to avoid a file changing between counts.

If you know the file is ASCII (and not UTF-8 for example), you could just reuse the byte count for the character count.